# updating xml payload in mule

Tags: xml, mule, mule-el

I am writing a Mule flow which expects xml as a input payload and returns xml output via http endpoint. I am performing some validation on the incoming xml and if it fails i want to return the same xml with some modification.

incoming xml:

```
<test>
<a>1</a>
<b>value1</b>
</test>
```

output xml:

```
<test>
<a>2</a>
<b>value2</b>
</test>
```

how can i update the xml values in Mule flow??

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use JAXB, it is FAST in Mule, and then you can use java to access it.

Use [This Tool](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx) to build your XML Schema

Use [XJC](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/) to create a JAXB object out of it.

Then in Mule you would use a XML to JAXB Object transformer, Do whatever you want with it, and then send it out with an JAXB Object to XML transformer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate the incoming **XML**, you can use extract the node values from the XML using **XPATH** in Mule ... here is the reference :-https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XPath

If you want to validate your input XML with an existing schema, the you can use Mule **Schema Validation Filter** ... reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Schema+Validation+Filter

And now, regarding updating/modifying xml, you can do it in Mule using **XSLT** trans former .. reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer